# What SE community to ask non-professional Networking Engineering questions?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Why doesn't SSH from ethernet connected device to wireless device work on local network](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74382/why-doesnt-ssh-from-ethernet-connected-device-to-wireless-device-work-on-local)

TLDR; **I'm fine with having my question closed**, I realize this is not the place for non-professionals; I'm not looking for an explanation as to why it was closed, I understand why (now). So what SE community should I go to for Networking Engineering questions that don't pertain to "Professionally Managed Networks"?

My question was closed because it states the Network Engineering SE community is for **Professionally** Managed Networks, and now that I know that I'll be sure to not return, it makes sense the moderators want to run a tidy, fat-free community; however, where should "non-professionally maintained network" questions be asked?

It seems that alot of people (including myself) have misunderstood the purpose of this community, I certainly will not pretend to be a networking professional, but for people who want to ask such question that are not welcomed in this community, where is it recommended for such questions to be asked?

Answer (score 1):

> So what SE community should I go to for Networking Engineering
> questions that don't pertain to "Professionally Managed Networks"?

As explained in the comment, [Super User](https://superuser.com/) is the place to ask about personal networks.

> It seems that alot of people (including myself) have misunderstood the
> purpose of this community,

Every SE site has a [Tour](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) and a [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, and you are expected to be familiar with those for an SE site before posting on the site. Unfortunately, there are many people who blindly post on SE sites without understanding the site rules.